Import Blender curve simulation into Maya
I made a simulation in Blender. My end result are moving curves. I would like to export them to Maya.
I tried all the formats (.abc, .fbx, etc.) and each time I got nothing once I import them into Maya, apart from an invisible geo file.


I have no Maya, but I'm quite sure it does not "understand" Geometry Nodes, the same goes for ABC or FBX files. To somehow export the result of the Geometry Nodes modifier, it has to be applied. Applying it though will not work, first of all it would not be an animated object but static as it was on the frame on which you applied the modifier, however applying will not work anyway with this nodetree because the Geometry Nodes modifier will only give mesh geometry as output when applied, but you are generating curves (so you could actually delete the Mesh to Curve node to apply it).

the simple answer: you can't because Maya doesn't understand geometry nodes and geometry nodes cannot be exported (yet). Your goal should be to "change" your geometry node modifier into a mesh and export that. I would try it with a python script. Or the tedious way: you apply the gn modifier for each frame  and store the result and make that visible/invisible (which is lots of work)
